# Typescript loop typed object

Tags: typescript, loops, types, typescript-typings

I have this validation file

```
interface Rule {
  required?: true;
  isNumber?: true;
  isDate?: {
    format: string;
  }
// ... some other rules
// ruleNames: RuleOptions
}

const RuleMap: {
  [key in keyof Required<Rule>]: (
    value: any,
    options: Required<Rule>[key]
  ) => boolean;
} = {
  required: (value) => value != null,
  isNumber: (value) => isNumber(value),
  isDate: (value, options) => isDate(value, options),
//...otherRules
}

// now I have a fairly strong typed object RuleMap
RuleMap.isDate('foo', { format: "DD/MM/YYYY" }); // no problem
RuleMap.required('foo', { format: "DD/MM/YYYY" }); // throws error
```

But when I try to do this

```
const myRules: Rule = {
  isNumber: true
}

(Object.keys(myRules) as (keyof Rule)[]).forEach((ruleName) => {
  // Expect this to be working
  RuleMap[ruleName](someValue, myRules[ruleName]);
  // This throws error
  // 'true | { format: string }' is not assignable to type '(true & { format: string })'
});
```

e.g:
When specifying `isDate`, `RuleMap` enforce me to input the exact `isDate`'s option for the function.

When looping for `Rule`, I expect the typescript to know that I am passing the exact `ruleName`'s ruleOption to the function.

Is it possible? If so, how should I do it?

Comment: The problem here is that typescript is working, it's throwing an error compilation since you can't apply the same arguments for different rules at the same loop without checking the types.

Comment: How do I let typescript know that I am passing the correct rule? In fact I am passing the correct rule right

Comment: You are looking for [io-ts](https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is exactly in stating that `myRules` is `Rule`, it means that TS doesn't know really what fields are in this object at the compile time, it treats it as `Rule`, so fields can or not be there.

Your loop is typed as it would go through all keys from `Rule` not from `typeof myRules`, in reality part of them are not there, but type system doesn't see that. At the value level it is obvious, that you go through `myRules` and if you do so field is there, but for type level `myRules` is just `Rule` and has keys for which value can be undefined. This is exactly the same what is happening in below simplified example:

```
const ruleName: "required" | "isNumber" | "isDate" = 'isDate';
const value = myRules[ruleName]; // value can be undefined!
```

The above is exactly what is happening inside `forEach` keys are typed as keys of `Rule` and value can be `undefined` what is in conflict with requirements of called function, requirement is stated as - `options: Required<Rule>[key]`, so it doesn't allow `undefined`. And here comes an error.

Ok so what can we do about that? The simple solution is to just work with direct type of `myRules` by using `const`:

```
const myRules = {
  isNumber: true
} as const; // pay attention here

(Object.keys(myRules) as (keyof typeof myRules)[]).forEach((ruleName) => {
  const value = 1; // example
  RuleMap[ruleName](value, myRules[ruleName]);
});
```

Works without errors because `ruleName` is always in the type, so `myRules[ruleName]` is never undefined. `const` allows type system to work with exactly the same shape of the object you have in runtime.

---

I assume you need it in some more real enviroment. In such we need to have generic which will allow as to work with exact narrowed type of `Rule` interface. Consider below example:

```
type OnlyKeysInRule<T extends Rule> = {
  [K in keyof Rule]: T[K]
} & {
  [K in Exclude<keyof T, keyof Rule>]: never
}
function doStaff<R extends Rule>(rules: OnlyKeysInRule<R>) {
  (Object.keys(rules) as (keyof OnlyKeysInRule<R> & keyof typeof RuleMap)[]).forEach((ruleName) => {
    const value = 1; // example
    RuleMap[ruleName](value,  rules[ruleName]);
  });
}
doStaff(myRules) // is ok
doStaff({isNumber: true, isHelicopter: false}) // error as expected - `isHelicopter` is not define in RuleMap
```

Explanation:

- `OnlyKeysInRule` is exclusive map which says - you can pass object which has only fields in `Rule`. Why it is important - because `R extends Rule` means type R can have additional fields, and that means `RuleMap[ruleName]` is not safe operation, as `ruleName` can be additional field not existing in `RuleMap`, this type prevents such.
- `as (keyof OnlyKeysInRule<R> & keyof typeof RuleMap)` we say we loop over only through keys in both `RuleMap` and `R`. Here TS is not able to infer that `OnlyKeysInRule` is already enough to prevent that, that is why union needs to be used.

Comment: Thanks! I indeed need that example for real environment!